# C/C++ technologies involved in sending data across networks very fast

Tags: c++, c, unix, tcp, network-programming

In terms of low latency (I am thinking about financial exchanges/co-location- people who care about microseconds) what options are there for sending packets from a C++ program on two Unix computers?

I have heard about kernel bypass network cards, but does this mean you program against some sort of API for the card? I presume this would be a faster option in comparison to using the standard Unix berkeley sockets?

I would really appreciate any contribution, especially from persons who are involved in this area.

EDITED from milliseconds to microseconds

EDITED I am kinda hoping to receive answers based more upon C/C++, rather than network hardware technologies. It was intended as a software question.

Comment: These usually *use* sockets -- they aren't nearly so much to reduce latency as to reduce the load on the main CPU.

Comment: @Jerry: Are you referring to checksum offload, or something more significant?

Comment: If you only care about *milli*seconds, bypassing the kernel isn't going to help you. I can't imagine that making a difference that can be measured except in microseconds.

Comment: I believe there are trading/exchange/pricing systems out there with considerably sub 1ms latency.  Real-time operating system (or highly tuned Linux) is probably the order of the day.

Comment: For distances of up to several decametres InfiniBand provides super high bandwidth and very low latency general purpose networking if programmed using its native interface (IP-over-IB is ssslllooowww). Some advanced Ethernet technologies like 10GbE and 40GbE come close at somewhat reduced cost.

Comment: @BenVoigt: More significant -- quite a few of them offload the *entire* process -- up to (and sometimes including) running an entire web server and/or browser on the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP sockets are fast, low latency, and reliable enough when both machines are on the same LAN.
TCP is much slower than UDP but when the two machines are not on the same LAN, UDP is not reliable.

Comment: Even on the same LAN, any point of congestion can cause dropped UDP packets - at sender, switch or receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Software profiling will stomp obvious problems with your program. However, when you are talking about network performance, network latency is likely to be you largest bottleneck. If you are using TCP, then you want to do things that avoid congestion and loss on your network to prevent retransmissions. There are a few things to do to cope:

- Use a network with bandwidth and reliability guarantees.
- Properly size your TCP parameters to maximize utilization without incurring loss.
- Use error correction in your data transmission to correct for the small amount of loss you might encounter.

Or you can avoid using TCP altogether. But if reliability is required, you will end up implementing much of what is already in TCP.

But, you can leverage existing projects that have already thought through a lot of these issues. The [UDT project](http://udt.sourceforge.net/) is one I am aware of, that seems to be gaining traction.

Answer (score 1):

At some point in the past, I worked with a packet sending driver that was loaded into the Windows kernel. Using this driver it was possible to generate stream of packets something 10-15 times stronger (I do not remember exact number) than from the app that was using the sockets layer.

The advantage is simple: The sending request comes directly from the kernel and bypasses multiple layers of software: sockets, protocol (even for UDP packet simple protocol driver processing is still needed), context switch, etc.

Comment: But surely the kernel-bypass technique would be even quicker?

Answer (score 1):

Usually reduced latency comes at a cost of reduced robustness. Compare for example the (often greatly advertised) [fastpath option for ADSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_digital_subscriber_line#Interleaving_and_fastpath). The reduced latency due to shorter packet transfer times comes at a cost of increased error susceptibility. Similar technologies migt exist for a large number of network media. So it very much depends on the hardware technologies involved. Your question suggests you're referring to Ethernet, but it is unclear whether the link is Ethernet-only or something else (ATM, ADSL, …), and whether some other network technology would be an option as well. It also very much depends on geographical distances.

**EDIT:**
I got a bit carried away with the hardware aspects of this question. To provide at least one aspect tangible at the level of application design: have a look at [zero-copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy) network operations like [`sendfile`(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile). They can be used to eliminate one possible cause of latency, although only in cases where the original data came from some source other than the application memory.

Comment: So how would this interface with a C++ program?

Comment: As long as you stay with the TCP/IP stack, this answer provides no aspect of the problem which can modify from within C++. If you change the underlying technology, you may also change protocols, and to do so, use a different API. E.g. to send raw ATM frames, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

As my day job, I work for a certain stock exchange. Below answer is my own opinion from the software solutions which we provide exactly for this kind of high throughput low latency data transfer. It is not intended in any way to be taken as marketing pitch(please i am a Dev.)This is just to give what are the Essential components of the software stack in this solution for this kind of fast data( Data could be stock/trading market data or in general any data):-

1] Physical Layer - Network interface Card in case of a TCP-UDP/IP based Ethernet network, or a very fast / high bandwidth interface called [Infiniband](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfiniBand) Host Channel Adaptor. In case of IP/Ethernet software stack, is part of the OS. For Infiniband the card manufacturer (Intel, Mellanox) provide their Drivers, Firmware and API library against which one has to implement the socket code(Even infiniband uses its own 'socketish' protocol for network communications between 2 nodes.

2] Next layer above the physical layer we have is a [Middleware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_oriented_middleware) which basically abstracts the lower network protocol nittigritties, provides some kind of interface for data I/O from physical layer to application layer. This layer also provides some kind of network data quality assurance (IF using tCP)

3] Last layer would be a application which we provide on top of middleware. Any one who gets 1] and 2] from us, can develop a low latency/hight throughput 'data transfer of network' kind of app for stock trading, algorithmic trading kind os applications using a choice of programming language interfaces - C,C++,Java,C#.

Basically a client like you can develop his own application in C,C++ using the APIs we provide, which will take care of interacting with the NIC or HCA(i.e. the actual physical network interface) to send and receive data fast, really fast.

We have a comprehensive solution catering to different quality and latency profiles demanded by our clients - Some need Microseconds latency is ok but they need high data quality/very little errors; Some can tolerate a few errors, but need nano seconds latency, Some need micro seconds latency, no errors tolerable, ...

If you need/or are interested in any way in this kind of solution , ping me offline at my contacts mentioned here at SO.